Get the most recent value in a table filtred by date in another table
I have the following tables in SSAS tabular cube:
F_Sales       : Invoice_key(FK), AMT
D_Invoice     : Invoice_key(PK), Productline_key(FK)
D_ProductLine : ProductLine_key(PK), Prd_key(FK), ProductLine_Type, ProductLine_Date
D_Product     : Prd_key(PK), Prd_Code
D_Situation   : Situation_key, ProductLine_key(FK), Situation_Type, Situation_Date

User filters : Date
             : He can choose or not a ProductLine_Type (optional)


I want to get the SUM(AMT) From F_Sales for every Prd_Code having the most recent ProductLine_Date with the associated Productline_Type filtered by Situation_date <= filter date chosen by user, for example:


Try something similar to:
Your Measure = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM(F_Sales[AMT]),
    TOPN(1, D_ProductLine, [ProductLine_Date], DESC)
  )

See more on TOPN
Second version to take into account Situation_Date being filtered in a one-direction relationship.
Your Measure = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM(F_Sales[AMT]),
    TOPN(
      1, 
      CALCULATETABLE(
        D_ProductLine,
        CROSSFILTER(D_Situation[ProductLine_key], D_ProductLine[ProductLine_key], BOTH)
      ),
      [ProductLine_Date], DESC
    )
  )


I tried the expression but it doesn't produce the expected result, i think it misses the Situation_Date to be included in the measure calcul

See second version above in the updated answer.
